# GCP composer environment settings - source bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to set a cloud composer environment gcs source bucket variable.

```
gcloud composer environments run airflow-composer-project --location us-west1 variables -- --set gcs_source_bucket gs://catalog_image_bucket
```

The error says it is a temporary error but it maybe with my syntax.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.composer.environments.run) HTTPError 502: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 502 (Server Error)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/ro
bot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{
background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelog
o_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.c
om/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>502.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

Comment: Is the bucket in the same project as Cloud Composer?

Comment: Yes, it is using the same project. But I initiated two buckets (one for a source and one for a destination) under the same composer project. I am trying to set the variables for the two buckets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update a variable you need to use the [update command](http://gcloud%20composer%20environments%20update):

```
gcloud composer environments update
```

The run command is to run [Airflow sub-commands](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/composer/environments/run)